# Networks Security Group best practices

Tags: azure, azure-security

Which are the best pratices to define Network Security Group in Azure?

All NICs need to have an NSG applied but is a best practice to create one for each NICs?

The best practice is to create one for enviroment (DEV, PROD, Staging)?

Comment: way to broad in my opinion. how are we supposed to know what fits your particular environment? usually 1 per subnet is the way to go (this at least makes sense from a management perspective), but who knows what is your network design\requirements

Comment: Definitely not an NSG per NIC. Generally one per environment, but depends. Also would suggest checking out Advisor (in the Azure portal), it'll prompt you if you're not following best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truthfully it will be different on how your network or organization is laid out.  I would definitely not recommend one NSG per NIC.  NSG are built to be reusable so if you have a group of VMs who will need the same configuration it would be best to attach them all to the same NSG.

As for one NSG per environment I'd advice against this as well as it assumes the rules will be be the same for all your appliances and services. (I know subnets can also be part of this but again how is the organization setup and/or appetite for managing all of that).

If it helps think of NSG as your firewall policy on inbound/outbound ports (just allow/deny).  Would you assign the same restrictions on every machine or PaaS offerring?  Probably not. Would it be the same in every environment, possibly but not likely.

As for deployment and management I'd strongly recommend leveraging [Azure Resource Manager (ARM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-syntax) templates and associate that with a CI/CD pipeline and potentially set it up for nightly deployments.  This would protect against configuration drift on your network if users are manually configuring nsgs.

Comment: Your advice is good, but this does not follow the Microsoft-CIS document that I mentioned in my answer. Microsoft does recommend two security groups. One for the network and another one for specific instances. There are good reasons for this, one of which is to prevent some users from adding rules to the network level security group while still allowing changes to the second security group.

Comment: Do you have documentation from Microsoft to support this?  Are you referring to how NSGs might be deployed into separate resource groups and then lock down the resource groups appropriately? I'd agree that is a good practice to separate who can update which NSGs.  [Microsoft's network best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/network-best-practices) does not reference any separation or hard number of NSGs..

Comment: I provided a link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft works with the Center for Internet Security to develop the `CIS Microsoft Azure Foundations Benchmark`. This document includes a section on network security best practices. This is an excellent document to read and includes individual steps to secure your Azure environment. This is the Azure recommend document.

Each of the steps detailed by the document are part of the Azure Security Center and Azure Monitor.

The document is copyrighted, therefore I can only include a link to the CIS website:

[Center for Internet Security](https://www.cisecurity.org/)